# Why is `this` undefined when implementing the event handling pattern?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype-programming

I am creating a library and one of the patterns I need to implement is event handling. I am writing in TypeScript, but this issue is basically in Javascript. Consider this code:

```
class MessageRelayer {
    private readonly listeners: Array<(args: string) => void> = [];

    public addListener(listener: (args: string) => void): void {
        this.listeners.push(listener);
    }

    public relayMessage(msg: string): void {
        for (const listener of this.listeners) listener(msg);
    }
}

class TestClass {
    private el: string;

    constructor(private readonly relay: MessageRelayer) {
        this.el = "example";
    }

    public initialize(): void {
        this.relay.addListener(this.onRelayed);
    }

    private onRelayed(e: string): void {
        console.log("EL is:", this.el);
    }
}

const relay = new MessageRelayer();
const stuff = new TestClass(relay);
stuff.initialize();

relay.relayMessage("Hello world"); // Error here
```

When running this code, it gives me error in `onRelayed`:

> Cannot read property 'el' of undefined

If `initialize` is written as:

```
public initialize(): void {
    this.relay.addListener((e: string) => { console.log("EL is:", this.el); });
}
```

It works.

### Questions

I understand this is about the famous `this` binding issue. But what's happening is not something I can explain here. What I think it should happen is:

1. When calling `initialize()`, function `TestClass.onRelayed` is passed to `MessageRelayer`. It means that in that moment, `this` for `TestClass.onRelayed` will be bound to `MessageRelayer`.
2. As soon as `relayMessage` is invoked, `MessageRelayer` will get the saved instance of `TestClass.onRelayed` whose `this` is now pointing to `MessageRelayer`, and executed it.
3. I should get an error that `this` does not contain `el`.

Instead I find out that `this` is actually `undefined`. What is happening here?

Comment: "*When calling initialize(), function TestClass.onRelayed is passed to MessageRelayer. It means that in that moment, this for TestClass.onRelayed will be bound to MessageRelayer.*" the value of `this` is determined *at call time*, not before that. So when you call `initialize`, you pass a function reference as the argument to `addListener` as `this.onRelayed` and disassociate it permanently from the `this` context, since when you call it it's just `listener()` - at *that* point there is not context for it.

Comment: They do not get `undefined` there, but the solution might be applicable. I would like to understand why I get `undefined here`. I am reading the question and the answer, if this is the same exact problem, I will delete the question.

Comment: Here is a rule of thumb *when you call* a function, `this` is set to whatever was before the last dot. So, if you *call* `a.b.c.foo()` then `this = a.b.c`. If you call `a.b.foo()` then `this = a.b`. If you call `a.foo()` then `this = a`. But if you call `foo()` then (to shorten it) `this = undefined`. If you do `bar = a.b.c.foo; bar()` then you are *not* calling with `a.b.c` as context, therefore `this = undefined`. See also [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: @VLAZ: Please post an answer, it seems to address the specific issue I am reporting here.

Comment: I see that the question you posted actually is the same, they are also getting `undefined`. I am voting to close as well.